# Wildfly GraphQL Smallrye @Routingcontext

Tags: graphql, wildfly, smallrye

I have setup a Wildfly 27 server with GraphQL Featurepack.

I need to access the Request Headers to fetch a bearertoken.

I find no good doc on how to do this.

My assumption is that i should inject the RoutingContext like this.

```
@GraphQLApi
@ApplicationScoped
public class FilmResource {

    @Inject
    GalaxyService service;


    @Inject
    RoutingContext routingContext;


    @Query("allFilms")
    @Description("Get all Films from a galaxy far far away")
    public List<Film> getAllFilms() {
        return service.getAllFilms();
    }
}
```

However this fails runtime with

ERROR [controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "cms-graph-ql-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description:
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."cms-graph-ql-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type RoutingContext with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject com.scanreco.cms.microprofile.graphql.FilmResource.routingContext
at com.scanreco.cms.microprofile.graphql.FilmResource.routingContext(FilmResource.java:0)

I would be greatful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured this one out.

Since i am using WF and not Quarkus i am forced to fetch the request headers via @Webfilter.

(Vert.x is not at all used for HTTP in my stack).

This is a minor inconvenince but quite alright.

```
@WebFilter(servletNames = {"SmallRyeGraphQLExecutionServlet"},
        filterName = "CMS Azure AD Filter",
        description = "Filter all ServletCalls for Azure AD Bearer token",
        dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST})
@RequestScoped
public class CmsGraphQlServletAzureAdFilter implements Filter {
```

The name of the executionservlet was found in their gitRepo.